# Two NSTextFields with interdependent widths in autolayout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

I’m trying to put together what seems to be a simple case of two NSTextFields with dynamic width and fixed spacing in between. I cannot figure out an effective way to do so though.

I’m looking to get something like this:

[image: Goal]

The blue boxes are the NSTextFields. When more text is entered into one, it should grow and thus make the other one shrink, maintaining the lead space, trailing space and the spacing in between the fields. The first one should take the priority if both of the fields have too much text. Each field will also clearly have a maximum and a minimum possible width it can reach.

[image: Examples]

How would I go around handling this, preferably utilising IB autolayout as much as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that all of constraints you mentioned directly translate into interface builder --

1. First view has width >= something.
2. First view has width <= something
3. Same for Second view.
4. Space between views is fixed.
5. Second view wants to be as small as possible (have its width at 0) but this has lower lower priority than the previous constraints and lower priority than inner content size constraints.

Comment: Thanks! This helped, although I still did end up having to add some manual size management code, on top of the IB constraints you described, to achieve the exact result I was after. I’ll add the snippet as an extra answer here, but will mark yours as the accepted one.

Comment: Can you add some more details about the constraints you used? I'm trying to configure a similar layout in IB (using Xcode 5.1), but not getting anywhere. With point 1 to 3, do you have each text field with 2 different constraints for width? Doing this confuses IB in my case. Also, with 5. is there a 3rd constraint (to make it zero)?

Answer (score 0):

The code I had to add to my view controller, after applying the constraints as per the ilya’s answer:

In `controlTextDidChange` (`_controlWidthConstraint` refers to the fixed width constraint of the input; it’s probably 0 by default for the second input):

```
// Get the new width that fits
float oldWidth = textControl.frame.size.width;
[input sizeToFit];
float controlWidth = textControl.frame.size.width;

// Don’t let the sizeToFit method modify the frame though
NSRect controlRect = textControl.frame;
controlRect.size.width = oldWidth;
textControl.frame = controlRect;

_controlWidthConstraint.constant = controlWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key lies in invalidating the `intrinsicContentSize` for the text field when text is input.

You can check a sample project [here](https://github.com/pedromancheno/TextFieldConstraintsExperiment), to get you on the right track.

Comment: This is about NSTextView no UITextView. Huge difference.